# can drupal core update using drush make problems?

Tags: drupal-7

I have an existing drupal page and I like to update to latest 7.34 version. I read, that it's possible using drush pm-update command. Can this command cause some problems on the site? It's on production server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As any other software, it's possible that drush could cause some issues. But anyway, drush is the recommended way to manage Drupal and that applies to pm-update command as well. You should consider making your own sandbox (dev environment) in order to test your actions before deploying your changes to any production server.